# Android icon not changing

Tags: android

I've developed several Android applications and this never happened to me, and is troubling my mind.
I have an application launcher icon named ic_launcher on the android several folders (xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi). My Android Manifest looks like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

And the application icon is simply the default android one. I've cleaned the project, refreshed, built from several different computers, used ant to crunch the png's and nothing.

I'm starting to think it's a problem with cached files on my Android or something (I use Miui on my S2) however I'm not sure.

Anyone have better suggestions?

Comment: Have you just try to uninstall and reinstall app on your device ?

Comment: Did you try to build your app on different devices?

Comment: try to keep the different name for the drawable and check it out

Comment: I've tried on other devices and the icon shows up. And yes I have tried to uninstall and re-install it.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? IMHO it is a Miui bug, because I have the same issue and I also use Miui on an S1. I also tried pretty much everything possible but nothing helps. Installing the app to an emulator works fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was with MIUI caching application icons. I searched and removed the existing icon and everything worked as expected from now then.

MIUI icon caching problem still present as of MIUI 9

**Step to clear caching:** Settings > Installed Apps > Search for your app > Storage > Clear cache > Restart your phone

Comment: I met the same problem. How did you remove cached icons?

Comment: Just change your theme, it will refresh the Icon cache

Answer (score 22):

I found that I had to delete ic_launcher.xml since this contains a path with the default icon encoded in it.

Comment: This worked for me in LG. I deleted ic_launcher.xml and ic_launcher_round.xml from res\mipmap

Comment: How insane it is ... was banging my head for last few days.. Thanks @Anthony

Answer (score 11):

Change your theme if you are using MIUI. Icon will refresh..

Comment: This fixed it for me in MIUI. Nothing from the previous answers (deleting app cache, deleting launcher cache, restarting phone) worked.

Answer (score 9):

I had this same problem, and rebooting the device made the new icon show up.

Comment: Thx, worked for me! So it is a cache problem, I think it is still in the RAM of the smartphone.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and checked around for similar posts. I deleted the bin directory and just had eclipse recompile and send the new apk to the device.

Comment: Where is the bin directory?!

Answer (score 1):

Andorid will take images depending on the DPI(Density in Pixels) your are using, since you are using **S2** my guess is that put your needed image into ***x-hdpi*** and check.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I was going to delete these icons from my res folder and build my application without them. If it can be installed to device, so it's probably some kind of cache yes, if it's not, I suggest you to change the name of your icon in your manifest and use another one just to see.

Comment: damn that's too weird..this is happening only with one device or with all of them?

Comment: I could only test on a specific galaxy S2, but it works fine on a LG and on a TF101.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in MIUI go to apps in setting and clear the data. Make sure that you restart your phone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem so i deleted the old icon from res file and after clearing cache restart the device and then it worked.

Comment: Clearing what cache?

Comment: go to system settings and then find your app and clear cache of your app and then restart your device.

Comment: thanks. Of course you don't mean the "System" section of settings within the settings app because that wouldn't make any sense (but that was the first place I looked when I read your comment). I did a search for my app by name at the top level of settings, something I didn't expect to work, and there it was and there was the clear cache option available when I tapped on it.

Comment: So @DavidRector is this solution works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see "classes/res-cache" folder in your project's root? If so, delete it. Helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens on some HTC devices. It's because the launcher caches the icon and does not refresh it even after your modification.

You can kill the process of your launcher to resolve it. Doing so works on my HTC One.

Answer (score 0):

If using Z-launcher, go to Z-launcher settings, then change the icon theme to something else and back to your desired value, icons will refresh

Answer (score 0):

Also remember to check dinamic xmls default icons on drawable and anydpi folders

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after searching a lot from internet, i have found that there is some kind of cache on the device on which we try to run the app, in order to clear the cache from that device, i have simply restarted my device and the icon updated on rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

All answers did not solve my problem, but they gave me an idea what to try and this was successful.

The advice in [Change the app icon from developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-change-app-icon#4) did not have the desired result in deleting only the files.

I will tell my solution for the ones finding this old question but the problem is for the current android studio in March 2024.

My setting is:

```
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-232.10300.40.2321.11567975, built on March 13, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 6.5.0-26-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3968M
Cores: 32
Registry:
    ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    hunspell (232.10300.41)

Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
```

Some more details: It is Ubuntu 23.10, Gnome 45, Android Studio installed from PPA https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maarten-fonville/android-studio/ubuntu/ (with this I hoped having no permission problems and I was right with this problem).

solution: In android studio in folder drawable I deleted both ic_launcher-XML-files. Then I deleted the folders beginning with 'ix_launcher' in folder mipmap bt the folder itself. Suddenly creating image asset lets me choose the ic_launcher-XML-files in the path-choosers.

Well, this has cost hours finding the solution (first I thought there are some strange permission problems which is often the case in linux-/unix-systems), but I found the strange problem created by android studio itself.