# react native app icon problem. App icon is not changing in app menu

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react native version 0.58.

I replaced my app icons with default ic_launcher.png in all mipmap folders.But app icon is still default android icon.I am sure that my png sizes are right for corresponding mipmap folder.

thanks

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.cekilissepeti">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: Check 'AndroidManifest.xml' file, under tag 'application' see where is address of app icon. And it's good for more information add your manifest code to your question.

Comment: Did you rebuild your app and not just reload it?

Comment: @Andrew yes i tried both react-native run-android and gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: @M.SamiAzar i edited my question with androidmanifest.

Comment: Did you change both 'ic_launcher.png' and 'ic_launcher_rounded.png'? And did you try to uninstall and reinstall again app on device ?

Comment: @M.SamiAzar yes i changed both. It doesnt work.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: any solution, i get same problem

Comment: If you're using MIUI you may need to switch theme.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529525/15609577

Answer (score 11):

I had to delete 'mipmap-anydpi-v26' from app/src/main/res folder which contained two xml files, one each, for both the normal icon, and the rounded icon.

Answer (score 6):

I had to rename the files to something different than `ic_launcher_round` and `ic_launcher`,

then I updated the `AndroidMaifest.xml`:

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_new_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/launcher_new_name_round"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MIUI on your phone you need to switch your theme.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529525/15609577

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is icons in `android/app/src/debug/res`
Some auto icon-generator tools throw icons in all android flavors

If you found icons there delete them, you should have only one place for icons under the `/main/res` folder

Answer (score 0):

I am using `react-native` version `0.68.2` and my **app icon was showing abnormal**

**Solution Worked for me:**

1. open project
2. cd `adroid->app->src->main->res`
3. see for folder named as **'mipmap-anydpi-v26'**
4. Delete the folder
5. rebuild your project.

**Enjoy!**

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same issue, with a similar `AndroidManifest.xml` to you, having used `yo` and `generator-rn-toolbox` to generate `@mipmap/ic_launcher` files.

However, since Android was using round icons, and the `yo` tool only generated `ic_launcher` and not `ic_launcher_round` files, I had to update the following value in `AndroidManifest.xml` and delete the `@mipmap/ic_launcher_round` files.

```
android:roundIcon=”@mipmap/ic_launcher”
```

Hope this helps.

Note: it is not best to use square images for round icons. In my case, I am waiting for [this PR](https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox/pull/216) to be merged so `generator-rn-toolbox` can generate round icons as well as square.